# Insufficient authentication scopes from Jenkins build via Google Compute Engine

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, gcloud

I searched the web for a while, but can't seem to find the right answer.

I have created a VM Instance on Google Compute Engine and I am running Jenkins on it. This instance checks a code repository I have and when a change occurs, I want to run the following command

```
gcloud --project=test preview app deploy -q app.yaml --version=dev
```

When I want to trigger a build, or it triggers it by himself, I get the following error:

```
Beginning deployment...
ERROR: Error Response: [403] Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not retrieve the default Google Cloud Storage bucket for [test]. 
Please try again or use the [bucket] argument.
```

The VM instance does have acces to the storage as you can see in the following image, so I don't understand why this error pops up.

[image: Permissions seem correct?!]

Comment: Is there any chance that the permissions for the storage bucket don't allow  access from the Jenkins instance? You could try working around by creating a [service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount) in the Cloud Console, and having Jenkins use that.

Comment: I already work via a service account in the Jenkins instance.

Comment: The screenshot you show is for a [Compute Engine service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication), which is different than a [developer service account](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2ServiceAccount). Which are you using?

Comment: Were you able to solve this issue? I am facing the same issue.

Comment: The solution is posted in [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33866201/jenkins-push-to-deploy-setup-for-app-engine-fails?answertab=votes#tab-top).

Answer (score 0):

Go to the App Engine developer console https://appengine.google.com/ and in 
Application Settings > Cloud integration > and turn ON the Google Cloud Storage

so this will set up the default bucket for you. This something that the new Google Developer Console will do automatically.If the project is created on the old console you have to do it manually.