# Jenkins push-to-deploy setup for app-engine fails

Tags: google-app-engine, jenkins, gcloud

I created a new compute engine instance from the bitnami-jenkins image to auto-deploy my app-engine application. I used the following command to do so:

```
gcloud compute instances create deployer
--project myapp --image-project bitnami-launchpad
--image bitnami-jenkins-1-638-1-linux-debian-7-x86-64
--zone us-central1-a --machine-type g1-small 
--metadata "bitnami-base-password=mypassword,bitnami-default-user=user,bitnami-key=jenkins,bitnami-name=Jenkins,bitnami-url=//bitnami.com/stack/jenkins,bitnami-description=Jenkins,startup-script-url=https://dl.google.com/dl/jenkins/p2dsetup/setup-script.sh" 
--scopes "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting,https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin" 
--tags "jenkins"
```

Once the machine was created, I created a job to deploy the code as described here:

> https://cloud.google.com/tools/cloud-repositories/docs/push-to-deploy

However, my job fails with the following error:

```
ERROR: Error Response: [403] Request had insufficient authentication scopes.
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Could not retrieve the default Google Cloud Storage bucket for [myapp]. Please try again or use the [bucket] argument.
```

Has anybody else encountered this? I had another jenkins machine with an older version of gcloud on it. It never threw any errors related to a cloud-storage bucket. So I have a hunch that it is related to newer versions of gcloud.

Please help. Thanks.

Edit: Here is the output of the gcloud command with `--verbosity debug`.
[gcloud output](http://pastebin.com/TwRJLLVm)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When I attempt to reproduce this using the latest version of the Cloud SDK (0.9.88), I get the following error message:

```
ERROR: (gcloud.preview.app.deploy) Required scopes ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform'] missing from ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/appengine.admin', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/devstorage.full_control', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/projecthosting', 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email']. This VM instance probably needs to be recreated with the missing scopes.
```

The solution is to re-create the VM, as before, but **add** the scope `https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform` to the list provided in the `--scopes` flag.

I'll make sure the documentation gets fixed to reflect this. **EDIT: the documenation is now fixed.**

Comment: Works after adding this to the scopes' list. Many thanks. :)

Answer (score 1):

**This answer is misleading; it misidentifies the real issue. I'm leaving it here for posterity.**

---

This looks like a hiccup in the interaction between Google Compute Engine Service accounts and Google Cloud Storage buckets.

To work around, please [create a Cloud Storage bucket](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/getting-started-console#create_a_bucket) that the [service account](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/authentication) on the Jenkins VM can read from/write to, or change the permissions on the Cloud Storage bucket `staging.<appname>.appspot.com`. The easiest place to do that will be the [Google Developer's Console](https://console.developers.google.com), if you're not familiar with [gsutil](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/gsutil?hl=en) (the command line tool to perform this operation).

---

> So I have a hunch that it is related to newer versions of gcloud.

Yes, it is. New versions of `gcloud` use a different deployment mechanism (which will be faster).

Comment: Thanks for the response Zachary, but my service account that is being used in jenkins (named myapp) already has 'owner' permissions to access the cloud storage buckets 'myapp.appspot.com' and 'staging.myapp.appspot.com'.

Comment: So, for instance, the following command succeeds? `touch foo && /tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin/gsutil cp foo gs://zjntestbucket2/foo`

Comment: That works. I was able to copy `foo` on `myapp.appspot.com` and `staging.myapp.appspot.com`. The only difference being `gsutil` was located at `/usr/local/bin` rather than `/tmp/google-cloud-sdk/bin`. But I continue to see the 'insufficient authentication scopes' error.

Comment: I have added the output of `gcloud` with `--verbosity` set to `debug`.

Comment: Thanks, the verbose logging helps. Taking a look now.